# Sign Up user with facebook in firebase

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, firebase

Hi every one I am trying to sign up users in my app using facebook connect botton. That is when the user click the button I check if it is first time i store some of his informatios if it is not his first time i just ligged into the app .Now I can logged the user when he click the botton get his information as showing bellow. **My problem is to save those informations in my Firebase App** but it is not working. Please any help will be great

```
//Here is the snapshot of my controller



var app = angular.module("yopi", ["firebase"]);
    app.controller("EventCtrl", function($scope, $firebase, $window) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://yopi.firebaseio.com/");


      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'MY API', // Set YOUR APP ID/
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
        {
         if (response.status === 'connected') 
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Connected to Facebook";
            //SUCCESS

        }    
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Failed to Connect";

            //FAILED
        } else
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Logged Out";

            //UNKNOWN ERROR
        }
        }); 

        };

        $scope.Login = function()
        {

            FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) 
               {
                    getUserInfo();
                    getPhoto();
                    $window.location.href = "https://yopevent.firebaseapp.com/events.html";
                } else 
                {
                 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
             },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos'});

        }

      function getUserInfo() {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {

              UserId = response.id;
              UserName = response.name;
              UserEmail = response.email;

        });
        }

        function getPhoto()
        {
          FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {


                $scope.Id = UserId;
                    $scope.Name = UserName;
                    $scope.Email = UserEmail;
                    $scope.PicUrl = response.data.url;

                    var newUser = {
                      UserId: $scope.Id,
                      UserName: $scope.Name,
                      UserEmail: $scope.Email,
                      UserPicUrl: $scope.PicUrl
                    };

//Here no probleme Iamgeting the oblect correctly in the console.


console.log(newUser);

//but the problem is here this is not svaing this objet in firebase
    ref.child("users").child($scope.Id).set(newUser);

    var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;


    });

  }

       $scope.Logout = function()
        {
            FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
        }

      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
    });
```

Comment: "it is not working" -> do you get any error message in the JavaScript console? What is the value of `$scope.Id` at the time you call `set(newUser)`?

Comment: Yes if i do `console.log($scope.id);` after the line `console.log(newUser);` it will print the faceboon Id of the user correctly.

Comment: OK, but there is no error message? Can you give an example of such a `$scope.id` value (to check if it makes a valid Firebase key)?

Comment: If I execute a similar `set` on your Firebase (but without data from Facebook), it works without problems. You might do well to set a breakpoint on the line that doesn't work and inspect all the values.

Comment: eh @FrankvanPuffelen the problem is solve i just passe the object directely like this and it works thanks for your help `ref.child("users").child($scope.Id).set({
        UserId: $scope.Id,
        UserName: $scope.Name,
        UserEmail: $scope.Email,
        UserPicUrl: $scope.PicUrl
      });`

Comment: That's exactly what I tested (with hardcoded values). But inline object vs variable should not make a difference. We must be overlooking a typo somewhere. But good to hear that you got it sorted. I'll vote to close as a typo, since it's unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: ok cool that is great